# I am working with Photoshop CC 2019 and I tried to write in Gujarati with Shruti font so it's not showing joined and non of them are working for me

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text

I am working with Photoshop CC 2019 and I tried to write in Gujarati with Shruti font so it's not showing joined and non of them are working for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only know this issue with Arabic in Indesign and Illustrator. But should be similar in Photoshop with this language.

Things to look out for:
– Is correct language set in Character Panel and Paragraph style.
– Is it set to single line composer in Paragraph Panel.
– Is correct text direction set: right-to-left or left-to-right I think Gujarati is ltr so probably does not apply for this.
– It may need the correct version of the app so you have all options to make this work (for example Arabic needs ME version so you have rtl options)
– Are standard ligatures activated in Opentype options.

Comment: Indic script aren't written right to left though.

Comment: Don't think so, but not sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_script